# Executar função mouseover em javaScript apenas uma vez

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, funções, eventos-do-mouse

tenho uma função que faz algumas ações dentro do meu html, o principal é, essa função faz uma requisição com ajax e me retorna uma lista que é incluída direto no select. preciso q ela faça era requisição apenas uma vez quando passar o mouse! porque toda vez que passo o mouse ele faz uma nova requisição e atualiza o select alguem consegue me ajudar?

```
$(".linha").mouseover(function () {

        var thDescricao = $(this).children('th.th-descricao');
        var thSimilar = $(this).children('.th-similar').children('select');

        var descricao = thDescricao.text();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'similaridade/' + descricao + '/',
            success: function (data) {
                thSimilar.html(data);
            },
            error: function (data) {
                thSimilar.html(data);
            },
        });
});
```

Comment: Cria uma variavel com valor 0, qndo passar o mouse alimenta ela com valor 1 e faz a verificação se o valor é 0 ou 1, se for 1 não executa o AJAX

Comment: faltou um complemento é uma tabela preciso fazer isso pra cada linha dela

Comment: a variavel bloqueia quando for fazer nas outras linhas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Podes usar o [`.one(`](https://api.jquery.com/one/) do jQuery. Ele vai disparar no máximo uma vez por elemento e por evento. No teu caso seria:

```
$(".linha").one('mouseover', function () {
```

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente, faz a requisição uma vez para cada linha

Comment: Mutio obrigado!